# ASP.NET MVC 5 Editor for 2-dimensional array

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model with two-dimensional array in it:

```
public class Matrix
{
    public ValidInt[][] Data;
    [Range(0, 8, ErrorMessage = "Введите ширину картины")]
    public int Width { get; set; }
    [Range(0, 8, ErrorMessage = "Введите ширину картины")]
    public int Height { get; set; }

    public Matrix(int w, int h)
    {
        Width = w;
        Height = h;
        Data = new ValidInt[w][];
        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
            this.Data[i] = new ValidInt[h];
    }

    public class ValidInt
    {
        [Range(0, 8, ErrorMessage = "Введите число, соответствующее цвету")]
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public ValidInt()
        {
            Value = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I would like to have HTML.EditorFor to fill data in each block, so I write something like that:

```
       <table>
            @for (int column = 0; column < Model.Data.GetLength(1); column++)
            {
                <tr>
                    @for (int row = 0; row < Model.Data.GetLength(0); row++) 
                    {
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Data[column, row].Value); </td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
```

But turns out you can't have EditorFor for two dimensional arrays. Any ideas on how to bypass that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use two-dimensional array. However, you could use [Jagged Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays).

***FYI:*** In order for ModelBinder to bind values to a model, it must have a parameterless constructor.

### Model

```
public class Matrix
{
    public int[][] Data { get; set; }
}
```

### View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        @for (int column = 0; column < Model.Data.Length; column++)
        {
            <tr>
                @for (int row = 0; row < Model.Data[column].Length; row++)
                {
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Data[column][row])</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

### Controller

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    int w = 3, h = 2;
    var matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.Data = new int[w][];
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
        matrix.Data[i] = new int[h];

    return View(matrix);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(Matrix matrix)
{
    return View(matrix);
}
```

### Result

[image]

[image]