# MVC Map array in model for passing model to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, ajax.beginform

I have form with several input buttons. Within this forms buttons can do actions. With 1st button I generate table(object with property of type int[,]). With the 2nd button I am going to do smth with this object. The first is ok, the 2nd returns null for model to controller. 
How to pass from form this object with array inside to controller? Now in SubmitForm method I have value for buttonType, but matrix is null(should be data from table).Appreciate any help

Model

```
public class Matrix
{
    public int[,] Data { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult SubmitForm(Matrix matrix, string ButtonType) - matrix is NULL here, how to get info from form
    {
        if (ButtonType == "Rotate")
        {
            return RotateMatrix(matrix);
        }
        //other code
    }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RotateMatrix(Matrix matrix)
    {
       //-some code
        return PartialView("_MatrixView", matrix);
    }
```

View

```
@model Project.Models.Matrix

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

var options = new AjaxOptions()
{
    UpdateTargetId = "Matrix",
};
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post, options))
{
  <div id="Matrix"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Rotate" name="ButtonType" />
<input type="submit" value="Generate" name="ButtonType"/>
}
```

PartialView

```
@model Project.Models.Matrix
<table>
    @for (int column = 0; column < Model.Data.GetLength(0); column++)
    {
        <tr>
            @for (int row = 0; row < Model.Data.GetLength(1); row++)
            {
                var item = Model.Data[column, row];
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item)</td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: where is your issue pleae be spsific, you want to submit data and recive it as array of integers ? or you submitting something null ?

Comment: Anyway please put your detailed code

Comment: @Mohammad Alghanem Hi, thank you for response. The problem is that on clicking submit button the method SubmitForm gets NULL model(Matrix class). I

Comment: @Mohammad Alghanem I've added piece of code from form,hope now it is clearer now

Comment: try use EditorFor not Display for and let me know

Comment: @Mohammad Alghanem I tried to change - have matrix instance with property Data NULL, instead filled array. Can it be the problem because of the array type?(I added model in the question description). Please, take a look

Comment: @Mohammad Alghanem I changed to EditorFor but the same issue

Comment: I found similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616052/binding-arrays-in-asp-net-mvc-without-index, but cannot catch the right way to bind 2d array property

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 5 Editor for 2-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409152/asp-net-mvc-5-editor-for-2-dimensional-array)